# Can I set up FBNativeDialogs to show "via MyApp" instead of "via iOS" in the feed?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

Is there a way to use the native iOS 6 FB sharing interface such that the posted feed item shows 'via MyApp' instead of 'via iOS'?

I've tried using both the `FBNativeDialogs` and `SLComposeViewController` but the result always shows 'via iOS'.

Comment: seems to be similar question http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12547616/sharing-with-ios-6-0-native-facebook-integration-posted-via-my-app-name

Comment: thanks for pointing me to that question. seems to be a good solution.